# vim: bad auto-indentation for bash

Tags: bash, vim

I'd like to have my bash scripts auto-indented within vim (using '='). If I take the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if :; then {
   echo 1
   echo 2
}
fi
```

the command "gg=G" will indent everything fine.
But if I write it as:

```
#!/bin/bash
:&&{
   echo 1
echo 2
}
```

"gg=G" will only indent the first line after '{', as shown.
Is there a possibility to let the code of the second example be indented nicely, too?

Comment: Might be worth asking on [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: P.S.: if I shift the '{' to the next line, it will cause following code-lines to be ill-indented.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9471/incorrect-auto-indent-in-bash-code)

Comment: @Holloway: I think my question is not a duplicate to that one You mentioned, because my bad behavior of vim occurs with "filetype indent on".

Comment: Fair enough. Thought it worth checking.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim` syntax script. Please contact DrChip, its maintainer, via email, and report this.